# Smart Contract Application in ASP>NET

Tags: ethereumj

I just have started to learn Smart Contract.  I have to design front end in ASP.NET. Can I call Contract from it?

Comment: yes you can there is web3 libraries for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frontend interacts with smart contracts with a blockchain usually using web3.js and [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js). This is purely client-side code written in JavaScript.

On the backend side in C# you can use [Nethereum](https://nethereum.com/).

A good starting point could be a [Web3modal tutorial](https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal-vanilla-js-example).

Comment: Okay will try Nethereum and let you know.  Thank you!

Comment: I checked Nethereum but I can't understand how to connect our uploaded contract or Deployed contract on local machine from .NET.  Can anyone suggest me any good code or link?

Comment: I cannot, I do not do C# programming. I suggest you contact directly Nethereum community and ask help.

Comment: Can you suggest me any other forum where I can found discussion about SMART CONTRACT and .NET CORE

Comment: No, as I said I am ont a C# developer. I would recommend learning Python and JavaScript intestead.